# How do you file a bug report for Windows?

Tags: windows-7

I have come across an issue that I feel is a [bug in Windows Media Player 12](https://superuser.com/questions/67129/windows-media-player-12-library-import-keeps-dying) in Windows 7. What is the official process for submitting an issue to Microsoft from a consumers perspective as an end user of Windows?

Comment: Nice, I encountered the same issue, in fact the only proper feedback place I found at Microsoft was http://connect.microsoft.com but it worked only for Visual Studio feedback/bugs. The question should be a a little bit more generic, not specific to WMP product.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no submit a bug report option directly. The way you do it is to call Microsoft Support and open a support request(can also be done online). If they can reproduce your issue and verify that it's actually a bug in WMP 12 they will file a bug report.

Be prepared to go through all troubleshooting steps they will have you perform, otherwise it will most likely never be reported as a bug.

Comment: It seems your answer [is far, far too optimistic](http://www.schveiguy.com/blog/2017/05/how-to-report-a-bug-to-microsoft/). The essence: guy has reproducible bug with code, calls Support, gets connected with people having no clue, sending him back and forth 70 minutes by telephone and stonewalling him completely. Some comments indicated that this is by purpose: Microsoft outsourced the whole thing and anyone who dare to connect to competent people will be fired.

Comment: This may have been true in 2009. But nowadays Windows includes Feeback Hub, which can walk you filing what amounts to a bug report. It even includes a screen recorder to help you demonstrate the bug.

Comment: It that's what requires me to go through to help microsoft, no thanks. It's like they don't want to get user feedback

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to fill in a bug submission form. Windows 7 makes it available through the Action Center an automatic Problem Reporting tool.

- Goto Start Menu and type `action center`. Hit enter.
- Click **Change Action Center settings** on the left sidebar
- Down the bottom of the new window, click **Problem Reporting settings**
- Make sure it is set to either one of the first 3 options: Automatically check for - solutions, or Automatically check for solutions and send additional data, or ask me before checking for solutions.
- Click Ok. You are back at Change Action Center Settings.
- Click **Customer Experience Improvement Program settings**
- Make sure you select the option to participate in the program

This is all you need for crashes, hangs and other windows related problems to be sent directly to Microsoft.

Manual online bug reporting tools are only available to subscribers of TechNet or MSDN.

Comment: I do have MSDN but I'm not able to submit bugs related to OS, only related to Visual Studio or other products.

Comment: Not every bug is a crash or hang.  Other bugs (it just does the wrong thing) will not be caught by that, so they have to be reported another way (either by Microsoft Connect (if available for that product), calling support, or some out of band way, like on Twitter or a blog post).

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows 10 there is an application "Feedback-Hub" preinstalled which can be used to send feedback to Microsoft. From [the Microsoft Help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332):

> The Feedback Hub app lets you tell Microsoft about any problems you run into while using Windows 10. You can also send suggestions to help us improve your Windows experience.

> The Report a problem and Suggest a feature buttons, which take you to the Feedback page where you can see if someone has already submitted the same report and upvote it, or submit a new report.