# To whom do I report a font bug in Windows?

Tags: windows, fonts

Windows 8.1 x64

In apps like the Windows Notepad and Notepad++, when using the font **Courier New, Bold Italic**, **size 9**, the lowercase letter "L" is displayed in uppercase.

I don't know if the problem is the font or some Windows engine.

Where should I report this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/526773/how-to-suggest-improvements-for-ms-windows-8, http://superuser.com/questions/622103/how-to-report-windows-8-bug-to-microsoft

Comment: Notepad++ isn't a Microsoft product thus if it has a font display problem then its not a Microsoft problem.

Comment: Well, Notepad may be using a Windows API to display the fonts, no? It happens on Windows and non-Windows apps, but they have the same OS in common.

Answer (score 0):

Well this can be Windows related so the best thing to do is to contact Microsoft

Here is some info that might help you

Microsoft Customer service: 1 (800) 642-7676

http://support.microsoft.com/